# Java conditional return terminology

Tags: java, error-handling, terminology

Java seems to make a distinction in its terminology between "errors", "assertions" and "exceptions." However, there is no defined terminology (that I can see) of a conditional check and return on failure (which up to this point, I have referred to as "error checking").

```
public int doSomething(int val) {
    if(val < 0) return -1;
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

In this example (although pointless) the method returns failure if `val` is negative, as a method for "error checking." However, Java specifically defines errors as those such as RuntimeException (hardware failure, etc). So what am I referring to?

Comment: I don't understand your question clearly

Comment: Exceptions, Errors and assertions are much more than terminology, they are language mechanisms, each with special handling by the JVM and are very different of veryfing a condition and distinguishing a special value as failure. (Which Java does not handle in any special way, and therefore, has no specific terminology for.

Comment: That pretty-much answers my question, thanks. It's the methodology I am going for, though. What is this process referred to? It can't be "error" checking because an error is something totally different in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions are for *exceptional* conditions; things you don't expect to happen (but are possible). Josh Bloch outlines this specifically in his book "Effective Java".

You'll find that many class' methods in java return true/false (boolean) as an indicator of success/failure *when failure is a common and expected condition*.

With that being said, it's never that easy. There's definitely things in the standard java classes that throw exceptions for common conditions, etc. Overall though, the first line of this answer is how I approach my own code.

Comment: So in your second paragraph, which describes something distinct from an "exceptional event," is that referred to as a general method failure? I'd like to put a name to it

Comment: I'm sure there's a fancy term for it but honestly, I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: I think the closest I could come up with is "input validation." However, I am still confused as to whether exceptions are acceptable in these situations based on what others have said. I think that's a complex argument (everybody has their own opinions). Which method is most widely accepted (maybe off topic)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call it [`return code`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status), just like the `exit status` of a process in general, return code in my view can also apply to methods.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question, I would refer to a pattern described in the book "Refactoring". (http://refactoring.com/catalog/consolidateConditionalExpression.html)

Programming I have learnt is best achieved when your code reflects your thought process and reads just the way you would like to think of solving your problem.

I would rephrase your code as

```
public void doSomething(int val) {
    if isValueInvalid(val) return ;
    ... // do something
    // returns should be modelled only if the client of this 
// program is expecting to use the results of this doSomething(..) for taking some action. 
}
```

Comment: I do take this approach sometimes, although I am looking for the terminology of this type of checking. It can't be called "error" checking, as Java has reserved "errors" as a specific type of problem that is totally unrelated.